# Using Pyphen with jython

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, jython-2.7

I am trying to run a Python script from a Java class using jython 2.7.0 and I need to use pyphen as part of the script. The following line in my Python script causes the following error message.

`from pyphen import Pyphen
ImportError: No module named pyphen`

My question is: Does jython have the capability to use the pyphen module?
And if jython can use the pyphen module, how do get it so jython knows about pyphen?